# Safe load for the Panasonic DW relay (ADW1205HLW)

Tags: current, relay

I'm lost and can't understand what are safe operating conditions for the relay I have.

In the datasheet (https://mediap.industry.panasonic.eu/assets/download-files/import/mech_eng_dw.pdf) it is stated that the max switching voltage of my relay **ADW1205HLW** is `277VAC` and `16A`, BUT if I look at the pins then I can't believe that this relay can handle such current more than several seconds. The pins are `0.8mm x 0.2mm` and this roughly corresponds to the `25AWG` wire. The `25AWG` wire can handle some `2 amps`.

This is **8 times less than in the datasheet**, not even mentioning that this relay is inrush type (up to `100A` inrush current).

How to understand what maximum current this relay can withstand in continuous operation mode?

Comment: Where did 2 amps come from?

Comment: From the pins / legs of the relay. They are tiny.

Comment: How did you calculate 2 amps; using what formula or table?

Comment: Measured contacts- they are 3 mm in length and have rectangle profile (0.8mm x 0.2mm) that corresponds to 0.16mm2 cross section area. And that corresponds to 25 AWG wire. Which can handle something around 2.7A if made from copper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The datasheet dimensions of the pins are 0.8mm x  0.4mm = 0.32mm^2 which is more like AWG 22.

A long piece of AWG 22 wire at 16A would get rather hot, but in this case the length of the pins is not so great and they will lose heat from the ends, so it's not really a problem.

Let's assume there's a 5mm length of pin and the current is 16A, the resistance will be 0.053Ω/m or 270uΩ. So power loss would be 70mW per pin, which is not very concerning. If they are actually 0.2mm rather than 0.4mm (how are you measuring it..) it's still not very concerning at 140mW.